# How to add multiple values under 1 column in database

Tags: django

I need to create a model that allows me to store multiple values under the same column. I'm not sure if this is possible or i'm thinking of the right way to do it. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=128)
SubtaskID = models.CharField(max_length=128)
SubtaskNode = models.CharField(max_length=24)
SubtaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In my project you can create a task which outputs a Task ID for later querying. And in a task there's n amount of subtasks created also. So i'm wondering how I could store the multiple values of the subtasks on my TaskID?

Example of structure of how they could look:

```
TaskID = c07de590-678f-45a2-b6ac-1110c201037b
SubtaskID1 = 87da261e-530d-40e8-8a8b-b61507c6eba2
SubtaskNode1 = Node1
SubtaskStatus1 = Waiting
SubtaskID2 = 140bb0a4-2cdb-46f0-b62d-9187592ae1e9
SubtaskNode2 = Node2
SubtaskStatus2 = Waiting
SubtaskID3 = 43e64d3a-a088-4aae-8a57-64e1c4dfba08
SubtaskNode3 = Node3
SubtaskStatus3 = Finished
SubtaskID4 = 324083fb-b9e9-471f-8946-21ed426fc646
SubtaskNode4 = Node4
SubtaskStatus4 = Failed
```

The purpose of all of this to later create a for loop in my template to list all SubtaskID's under the TaskID value.

Comment: Consider [many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: @kichik Seems like the way to do it. Thanks, bud!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a self reference, where a task record references a parent task record, that references task record, ... , and son on.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    status = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='subtasks')
```

You can query for a task subtasks like this:

```
subtasks = Task.objects.get(id=id).subtasks
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to keep Tasks and SubTasks in different models and use ForeignKeys to link them to each other.

Your question title is a bit misleading, btw.